# react-semantic-ui-datepickers no form value in redux-form

Tags: datepicker, redux-form

This issue applied the standard implementation without additional customisations.
The is no value on submit of the form and onChange does not fire with the current value.

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
            <Form.Group>
                <Field
                    component={SemanticDatepicker}
                    name="working"
                    dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
                    label="Date of birth"
                    placeholder="select your DOB"
                    size="small"
                    onChange={(e, value) => {
                        console.log(e, value);
                    }}
                />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Field
                control={Button}
                color="purple"
                className="submit-btn"
                type="submit"
                width={6}
            >
                Save
            </Form.Field>
        </Form>
```

A minimal version can be found here https://github.com/chrishj59/datepickerIssue

Answer (score 0):

I could capture the `onChange` value by creating a custom component which wrapped the `<SemanticDatepicker />`. I also added `mapStateToProps` to log the `redux-form` values. You can consider this as a starting point and work on this.

```js
//SongList.js
state = {
  date: "",
};

render(){
  const DatePick = () => {
  return (
    <SemanticDatepicker
      onChange={this.datePickerOnChange}
      format="YYYY-MM-DD"
    />
  );
};
return (
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
    <Form.Group>
      <Field
        component={DatePick}
        name="working"
        dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
        label="Date of birth"
        placeholder="select your DOB"
        size="small"
      />
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Field
      control={Button}
      color="purple"
      className="submit-btn"
      type="submit"
      width={6}
    >
      Save
    </Form.Field>
  </Form>
);
}
```

```js
//App.js
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const App = (props) => {
  console.log(props.form);
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <SongList />
    </div>
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  form: state.form,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve using semantic-ui-redux-form-fields to wrap the Semantic UI component. This now gives the correct format and value appearing in the validate function and formProps.

```
import React from "react";
imp ort { fieldEnhance } from "semantic-ui-redux-form-fields";
import { compose } from "redux";
import SemanticDatepicker from "react-semantic-ui-datepickers";
import "react-semantic-ui-datepickers/dist/react-semantic-ui-datepickers.css";

const DatePickerPure = (props) => {
    const { currentValue, input, ...rest } = props;
    const defaultProps = {
        format: "DD/MMM/YYYY",
        onChange: (event, data) => input.onChange(data.value),
        value: currentValue,
        ...rest,
        };
        return <SemanticDatepicker {...props} {...defaultProps} />;
     };

   export default compose(fieldEnhance)(DatePickerPure);
```